# Ignore C comments and include statements using sed (//, /**, **/, #)

Tags: regex, shell, sed

So I've got some example C code

```
/**
example text
**/
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int example = 0;
    // example text
    return;
}
```

How would I specifically use `sed` to ignore all lines starting with `//` or `#` while also ignoring lines in the range of `/**` to `**/`?
I've tried things along the lines of `sed -E '/(^#|\/\*/,/\*\/|^\/\/)/!s/example/EXAMPLE/g'` but I have a feeling I'm not using the `|` correctly as it pops an error saying "unmatched ("

My desired final output should be

```
/**
example text
**/
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int EXAMPLE = 0;
    // example text
    return;
}
```

The change from the sed command would have changed instances of the word "example" in the program to the uppercase version "EXAMPLE", and what I'm trying to do is make sure words on commented lines are not being changed.

Comment: Why would you do this with sed?

Comment: You're not going to be able to ignore lines with c style comments, Not going to happen. Mainly because you have to match string quotes along with matching comments. And the word _matching_ comes up, which isn't what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without ignoring the possibility to fall into circumstances that `sed` will not be the right tool for this job as sin and melpomene mention in comments, the bellow command will do the trick in your particular exercise:

```
sed -E '/(#|\/\/)/b ; /\/\*\*/,/\*\*\//b; s/example/EXAMPLE/g' file
/**
example text
**/
#include <stdio.h> example

int main(){
    int EXAMPLE = 0;
    // example text
    return;
}
```

`sed` special word `b` makes use of labels:

> 'b LABEL'
>        Unconditionally branch to LABEL.  The LABEL may be omitted, in
>        which case the next cycle is started.

In other words, instead of negating a pattern like `/pattern/!` you can use `/pattern/b` without a label and when `/pattern/` is found sed jumps (because of `b`) to the next cycle skipping the substitution `s/example/EXAMPLE/g` command.

Your attempt does not work because you try to use logical OR `|` in a mix of patterns like `#` or `//` and also a range like `/\/\*\*/,/\*\*\//`